# wifi problem in sony vaio

Tags: wireless

how can i use wifi in ubuntu13.04.in the system settings wifi hardware is not displayed. I am using sony vaio vpceh25en.when i run this command in terminal `rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

1: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

2: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

this message came.please somebody help me to activate my wifi..thanks

Comment: `Hard Block : yes` means either the wi-fi switch (may be a Function key combo or a separate switch at site) is not ON or the driver is not present. Please edit your question and include result of `lspci`, `sudo lshw -c network` if the switch doesn't resolve the case.

Answer (score 0):

Hard blocked means that your wireless is blocked by hardware.
If there is a switch to turn on wifi check if it is turned on.

and check to see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: `rfkill unblock all` has nothing to do with hard block. It is only applicable to soft block.

Answer (score 0):

According to these sony docs- [Sony Docs](http://www.docs.sony.com/release/vgnfs600-a790.pdf) there is a slider switch near the screen where all the lights are.